# Get First GUID type value from List

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, arraylist, guid

I have a list of an string, which can hold up data of any data type ie

```
    [0]: ""
    [1]: "api"
    [2]: "Lookup"
    [3]: "user"
    [4]: "MapDesignation"
    [5]: "84e57c3c-51d2-4e4d-a7ae-db2ee088a3c6"
```

Code:

```
"/api/Lookup/user/MapDesignation/84e57c3c-51d2-4e4d-a7ae-db2ee088a3c6".Split('/')
```

Now my requirement is that I need to get the first GUID value from this list.
The list can hold up multiple GUID type value, but I need just the first one.

Thanks

Comment: "/api/Lookup/user/MapDesignation/84e57c3c-51d2-4e4d-a7ae-db2ee088a3c6".Split('/').OfType<System.Guid>().First();    I have this, but getting 'System.InvalidOperationException', can you please look is there anything missing

Comment: You should just be able to iterate and then use Guid.TryParse on each element to see if its a valid GUID.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @John - Because the link you posted showed searching a list looking for a particular type. The question relates to searching a list or string looking for something that may be converted to a particular type.

Comment: @Sean OP's question is ambiguous then: they state they have a list of object type (i.e. `List<object>`) and that the want to take the first `Guid`.

Comment: @Sandeep, please could you edit your question to clarify - ideally provide a sample of how to create the list, etc.

Comment: If it really is a real `Guid` in that list of `object` then you can just do: `var guid = myList.OfType<Guid>().First()` or (if the Guid can be missing) `var guid = myList.OfType<Guid>().FirstOrDefault()` (then check guid isn't `Guid.Empty`).

Comment: ..but actually from your first comment, it seems like this really is a list of strings. You're going to have to clarify!

Comment: @Sean the solution given by you worked, tried actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Where(d => Guid.TryParse(d.ToString(), out val)).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've got the data in a string list of some sort:

```
List<string> data = ....;
string value = data.Where(d => Guid.TryParse(d, out var _).FirstOrDefault();
```

If there's no valid guid in the list then `value` will be `null`.

If your list is a list of object then you can try converting the value to a string and then parsing:

```
List<object> data = ....;
var value = data.Where(d => Guid.TryParse(d.ToString(), out var _).FirstOrDefault();
```

If the list contains a series of types, which might include a `Guid` then you can use `OfType`:

```
List<object> data = ...
var guid = data.OfType<Guid>().FirstOrDefault();
```

In this case if the there isn't a guid then `guid` will be set to `Guid.Empty`.